# Can a role that has ACCOUNTADMIN under it successfully query TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to query size of databases, schemas, tables for better management. I have a role (say called ABC) that has ACCOUNTADMIN under it.  However, when I query TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS it comes back full of nulls.  Using the actual ACCOUNTADMIN has it fully populated.

Why wouldn't role ABC be able to query it if ACCOUNTADMIN is under it?

Comment: What does "under it" mean?

Comment: Hearing the grants to the role in question would help us understand better. In general, the ACCOUNTADMIN role is the "superuser" in Snowflake and it would not be a best practice to grant this to other roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@karthik - Recommendation 1

Try below

`USE ROLE accountadmin; 
 USE SCHEMA snowflake.account_usage;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe ABC role given by account admin. May this role don't have privileges to access the metrics table.

Check access privileges for role - ABC.